# Как придумать, что автоматизировать в работе за ПК?

Tags: автоматизация, пк

Часто слышу от умных дядек, что чтобы получить опыт в программировании, напишите полезные для себя програмки. Например автоматиризуйте какую-то работу на своем пк.
Вроде интересно, а идей ноль(0). Ничего не в голову не приходит.

Что я делаю за пк - пользуюсь IDE, браузером, иногда Adobe pdf, Steam(игровая платформа), блокнотом(что-то записать, чтоб не забыть), ну и впрочем все наверное.
Как придумать, что автоматизировать? Просто нет вроде никаких нужд особо, но очень хочеться над чем-то полезным поработать, покодить.

Обо мне: Знаю Java на достаточном уровне, Spring, Hibernate(оба на начинающем уровне). Какие можете примеры дать может со своего опыта, что вы сделали для автоматизации своей работы за пк.

Comment: Пользуетесь браузером. Интерфейсом часто посещаемых сайтов довольны? Например, яндекс-переводчик или гугл-транслейт: в них можно послушать произношение слова, но нужно мышкой кликать по значку. Сделайте шорткат взамен. Вбил слово, нажал шорткат, не снимая руку с клавиатуры на мышку, послушал голос.

Comment: Не пользуюсь голосом:) А где может есть сайтик с примерами разных таких скриптов, которые помогают програмистам в повседневных проблемах?)

Comment: напишите трассировщик лучей https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9

Comment: Необходимость в програмках возникает в процессе работы) Подумайте какие задачи у вас самые рутинные, может быть что-то придет в голову.

Answer (score 1):

Напиши плеер, который будет тянуть музыку с ВК. Я начинал с этого.

Напиши переводчик, который по нажатию комбинации клавиш переведет выделенный текст.

Можно сделать клиента для гугл диска.

Comment: а как понять, как это все делается?) потому что даже не имею представление, как это делать

Comment: А плеер ещё работает?

Comment: @ekstra777, учить vk api и api google диска

Comment: @Александр найти бы его.. их даже несколько было. первый на cairo, второй на qml. сомневаюсь что ещё работает. писалось на апи версии 2 или 3

Answer (score 0):

Лично у меня во-первых есть скрипты, которые любую чистую убунту или арч превращают в полностью готовую и настроенную под мои нужды среду - устанавливают все необходимые мне программы, обновляют до последних версий, тащат конфиги с репозиториев и линкуют их в нужные места.

Во-вторых я занимаюсь разработкой настольных игр в Second Life (в основном просто хобби, но и денег немного приносит), так вот, скриптами я собираю сайты с документацией (на основе markdown) к своим проектам и делаю коммиты.

Comment: Звучит круто, хоть я большую половину не понял(особенно про второе) хех.

У меня не линукс, а виндовс, что можно сделать для винды полезного например?)

Comment: Да фиг его знает. В винде терминал не в моде, потому и шелл-скрипты не популярны. Когда у меня была винда, я для всяких мморпг писал скрипты на AHK, которые автоматически сражались и выдавали комбо в пвп. Читерство конечно, но в целях саморазвития полезно.

Comment: ты может не правильно меня понял. Я не хочу особо делать что-то на скриптах терминала прям.
Хочу практиваться на Java, пописать что-то полезное для себя или хотябы просто интересное, не используюя фреймворки, а просто Java SE

Comment: @ekstra777 можно конечно и полноценные утилиты писать для автоматизации, на той же джаве, но скрипты же проще и лучше подходят для этих целей

Comment: @ekstra777 если бы я увлекался джавой, наверно начал бы с модов на майнкрафт или вроде того

Comment: не увлекаюсь такими помоями как майнкрафт, сори:) из игр только те что в стиме могу поиграть, типа дота, кс , ну еще в фифа.

Comment: @ekstra777 ну найди не помои на джаве. Можно на том же гитхабе открыть список java-проектов, найти что-то интересное и форкнуть.

Comment: https://github.com/topics/java